# Multiple image upload with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, image-upload

I'm new to RoR so this is probably a 5 min task for most of you.

I want to upload multiple images using paperclip - initially I set up the app to upload a single image using paperclip. I've now added a separate assets table and used 'nested attributes' for the relationship but getting lost of errors.

Certain it's something really obvious and most likely to do with changing from uploading a single image and introducing a separate assets table for multiple images.

The app is saved here. https://github.com/KiwiChristy/Pinteresting

Thanks

Comment: efforts of research on web?

Answer (score 0):

**Form**

```
#app/views/images/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @image do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
   #app/controllers/images_controller.rb
   def new
      @image = Image.new
   end

   def create
      @image = Image.new(image_params)
   end 

   private

   def image_params
      params.require(:image).permit(image: [])
   end
```

**Model**

```
#app/models/image.rb
Class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image
end
```

Good resource: https://gist.github.com/patrickberkeley/33011